# Android - Listen to BaseActivity variable value change

Tags: java, android, listener

My code has a `BaseActivity`, which extends from `Activity`. It has an expansable menu.
Other activities are "opened inside" `BaseActivity`'s frame. I need to check when user expand or collapse the menu to resize columns from a activity opened in `BaseActivity`.

**ExpandObserver.java**

```
public class ExpandObserver {

    public interface IExpandListener {
         void resizeIfExpanded(boolean isExpanded);
    }

    private IExpandListener listener = null;

    public void registerListener(IExpandListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void listenExpandChange(boolean isExpanded) {
        if (this.listener != null) listener.resizeIfExpanded(isExpanded);
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java** (relevant code)

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements ExpandObserver.IExpandListener {

    private ExpandObserver expandObserver = null;

    //onCreate
    expandObserver = new ExpandObserver();
    expandObserver.registerListener(this);
    //... 

    //Inside expand method
    // expand is a BaseActivity private variable used to control if is collapsed or not.
    expandObserver.listenExpandChange(expanded);
}

@Override
public void resizeIfExpanded(boolean isExpanded) {

}
```

**MyListActivity.java**

```
public class MyListActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void resizeIfExpanded(boolean isExpanded) {
        //HERE I NEED TO CHANGE COLUMN SIZE 
    }
}
```

**MyListActivityAdapter.java** (I need to resize to my custom ListView items)

```
public class MyListActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void resizeIfExpanded(boolean isExpanded) {
        //HERE I NEED TO CHANGE COLUMN SIZE 
    }
}
```

Any thoughts about how make it done? I have tried several codes but still not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "expanded inside BaseActivity's frame"?  It sounds like you should be using fragments.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not using Fragments. BaseActivity has a fixed header and a side menu, with a "space" to load activities according to side menu. That's what I meant, this space to load.

Comment: Then you absolutely should be.  You should never be using activities like that, that's what a fragment is for.

Comment: @GabeSechan that's the problem... it's a legacy app and we don't have time to change its architecture :( any workaround?

Comment: Yes, but it turns the code into even more spaghetti than it is now.  Have a singleton global messaging queue.  Have the subactivities register themselves as listeners in onStart (and remove in onStop).  Have the menu generate these messages when they're used.  The messaging queue will notify all registered listeners.  It turns your entire code base into unmaintainable spaghetti over time, but it will work as a quick hack.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for clearing up this mess. Sadly I'll try something like you suggested me. It's not the ideal, but will do it.